# Assign a user to a workspace using asana API

Tags: asana

Is it possible to assign a user to a workspace through asana API. The documentation [here](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/users)  doesn't seem to be making any mention of it.

Is it possible to assign a user to a workspace if we have the API keys to both the asana accounts(i.e one belonging to the user and the other of the user to which the workspace belongs)

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently support managing workspace members via the API, however we have made significant progress towards supporting this. We're currently weighing some security considerations, though, so it's hard to say when we'll be able to launch this. Sorry, I'm sure that's frustrating to hear.